# replace ending brackets with another string in bash

Tags: bash, sed, tr

I would like to replace the last 3 lines with another string.. using `sed`, `tr`, or other `bash` solution.

Given file:

```
{
  [
    {
      text text text
      text text text
      text text text
    }
  ],  
  [
    {
      text text text
      text text text
      text text text
    }
  ]
}
```

desired result:

```
{
  [
    {
      text text text
      text text text
      text text text
    }
  ],  
  [
    {
      text text text
      text text text
      text text text
bar
```

I tried this with `sed`

```
sed -i '' 's/\}\s+\]\s+\}/bar/g' foobar.hcl
```

tried this with `tr`

```
tr -s 's/\}[:blank:]\][:blank:]\}/bar/g' <foobar.hcl
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please share with us.

Comment: I adjusted the description and added what I tried

Comment: please update the question to also show the desired result

Comment: will the 3 lines you're looking to replace always be the last 3 lines of the file? could the 3 lines also show up somewhere else in the file? could there be multiple occurrences of these 3 lines?

Comment: @markp-fuso they are the only occurrence, yes, but it might be that they are followed by empty lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `perl` where you can read entire input as a single string using `-0777` option. Not suitable if input is large enough to run out of available memory.

```sh
# this will replace all remaining whitespaces at the end
# with a single newline
perl -0777 -pe 's/\}\s+]\s+\}\s*\z/bar\n/' foobar.hcl

# this will preserve all remaining whitespaces, if any
perl -0777 -pe 's/\}\s+]\s+\}(?=\s*\z)/bar/' foobar.hcl
```

Once it is working, you can use `perl -i -0777 ...` for in-place editing.

Comment: Amazing this works! I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1N;:a;N;/^\s*}\s*\n\s*]\s*\n}\s*$/{s//bar/;N;ba};P;D' file
```

Open a 3 line window and pattern match.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array - assumes "text text text" has some actual nonspace, non-punctuation characters.

```
mapfile x < file                                # throw into an array
c=${#x[@]}                                      # count the lines
let c--                                         # point c at last index
until [[ "${x[-1]}" =~ [^[:space:][:punct:]] ]] # while last line has no data
do let c--                                      # decrement the last line pointer
   x=( "${x[@]:0:$c}" )                         # reassign array without last line
done
x+=( bar )                                      # add the desired string
echo "${x[@]}" > file                           # write file without unwanted lines
```

Allows for any number of blank lines &c. Even `}]}` and such, so long as it isn't on the same line with the data.